# Why there are unwind symbols present in my shared library

Tags: android, c++, compilation, symbols, static-linking

I am using readelf on one of the shared libraries I have. When I read the symbols, the list containing lot of unwind symbols like below.

> 23: 001e0c48 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_Resume
>
> 5998: 00000000 0 FUNC WEAK DEFAULT UND __gnu_Unwind_Find_exidx
>
> 5999: 001e0b54 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Restore_VFP_D
>
> 6000: 001e0b44 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Restore_VFP
>
> 6001: 001e0b64 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13
>   __gnu_Unwind_Restore_VFP_D_16_to_31
>
> 6002: 001e0b74 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Restore_WMMXD
>
> 6003: 001e0bfc 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Restore_WMMXC
>
> 6005: 001e0080 8 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_GetCFA
>
> 6006: 001e0088 164 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_RaiseException
>
> 6007: 001e012c 28 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_ForcedUnwind
>
> 6008: 001e0148 116 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Resume
>
> 6009: 001e01bc 32 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13
>   __gnu_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow
>
> 6010: 001e01dc 4 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_Complete
>
> 6011: 001e01e0 24 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_DeleteException
>
> 6012: 001e01f8 92 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_VRS_Get
>
> 6013: 001e027c 92 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_VRS_Set
>
> 6014: 001e0304 200 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Backtrace
>
> 6018: 001e07d0 864 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_VRS_Pop
>
> 6019: 001e0b5c 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Save_VFP_D
>
> 6020: 001e0b4c 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Save_VFP
>
> 6021: 001e0b6c 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13
>   __gnu_Unwind_Save_VFP_D_16_to_31
>
> 6022: 001e0bb8 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Save_WMMXD
>
> 6023: 001e0c10 0 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 __gnu_Unwind_Save_WMMXC
>
> 6025: 001e0c24 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 ___Unwind_RaiseException
>
> 6026: 001e0c24 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_RaiseException
>
> 6027: 001e0c48 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 ___Unwind_Resume
>
> 6028: 001e0c6c 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 ___Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow
>
> 6029: 001e0c6c 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow
>
> 6030: 001e0c90 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 ___Unwind_ForcedUnwind
>
> 6031: 001e0c90 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_ForcedUnwind
>
> 6032: 001e0cb4 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 ___Unwind_Backtrace
>
> 6033: 001e0cb4 36 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_Backtrace
>
> 6035: 001e113c 16 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_GetRegionStart
>
> 6036: 001e114c 28 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13
>   _Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData
>
> 6037: 001e1168 8 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_GetDataRelBase
>
> 6038: 001e1170 8 FUNC GLOBAL DEFAULT 13 _Unwind_GetTextRelBase

I checked the source code of library but could not find references to these symbols. I am guessing, while compiling the source files or linking into library they might have used some flag to generate these symbols.

Any idea which clang++ flag is used to generate these symbols?
And what is the use of these symbols?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is the exception handling, if you do not use exception, you may compile with `-fno-exceptions`

see https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libgcc-sman.html